# Connect an Object to an item in a Treeview Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I created a ttk/Treeview Widget in Tkinter using Python 3. I would like to connect an object to its name which is listed in the tree view. To illustrate this I created following example.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class myclass:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name=name
        self.value=value

class maintree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, master):        
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.my_objects= [myclass("object"+str(_), _) for _ in range(1,11)]
        for my_object in self.my_objects:
            self.insert("", "end", text=my_object.name)

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    maintree(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this example I would like to get the my_class instance corresponding to the selected name in the treeview to do something (ie, display the value of the currently selected my_class object).

I only know about the item IDs but I don't know how to connect something to an item itself. I have the feeling that I have some misconception about how treeview is supposed to work.

I appreciate your Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `insert` method has no `command` option. However, you can tag each inserted item and bind the tag to an event. So, I used the object name as tag and then bound it to execute some method of the object on mouse left click.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name=name
        self.value=value

    def callback(self, event=None):
        # event=None is a trick to be able to call the method both directly and 
        # from a binding (that will pass the event argument to the function)
        print(self.name, self.value)

class MainTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, master):        
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.my_objects= [MyClass("object"+str(_), _) for _ in range(1,11)]
        for my_object in self.my_objects:
            self.insert("", "end", text=my_object.name, tags=(my_object.name,))
            self.tag_bind(my_object.name, '<Button-1>', my_object.callback)

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainTree(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: First: Thank you very much! Further: Can I extend this method in order to handle selection changes by other method (for example by using the arrow keys) as well?

Comment: I use `id(my_object)` for the tag name now since this gives my a unique id for every object. Also adding `self.tag_bind(id(my_object), '<Return>', my_object.callback)` after the `self.tag_bind...` line lets you carry out the callback by keyboard which comes close to what I asked for in my earlier comment.

Comment: After looking into the properties of the Treeview widget, I found on http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview-events.html that "Whenever there is a change in the selection, either by items becoming selected or becoming unselected, the widget generates a “<<TreeviewSelect>>” event". So replacing "<Button-1>" by “<<TreeviewSelect>>” should do what you want.